# Universal Input Driver

Tags: c++, c, input

To begin, I am building a simple gamepad and I was wondering if there is anyway that I can program a universal driver, what I mean by that is that so the input to be passed in by the gamepad (buttons, axes, etc) are built in one driver and that one driver is compatible with many systems.

I have searched everywhere but cannot find an answer to my solution. I see companies like logitech and other gamepads, whenever I plug the gamepad into any system it works, how do I program my device to do that?

**--Edit--:**

The connection between the host and my device is through bluetooth. But I already have that part taken care of, the data transmits successfully. The hard part is building the driver that will submit the input from gamepad to the actual game.

Comment: Retagged; I barely believe that ONE driver is compatible with every OS. This is just not true...

Comment: I think these devices are pure USB HID-class devices, and the HID-class driver is provided by the OS itself.

Answer (score 2):

Drivers control hardware, and drivers are written at OS level, and deal with OS specific ways of dealing with hardware.  There is no universial, cross platform way to write a driver, because each different OS works differently at kernel level.

Windows Drivers and Linux Drivers are written in a different ways, because they handle hardware differently.

You will have to write a driver for each OS you want to support.

Comment: But how do I actually build a driver for say windows to handle the input and identify it as gamepad input?

Comment: Depends on the gamepad. Generic ones usually work like keyboards, but I'm pretty sure, say, the Microsoft XBox wireless gamepad does not.

Comment: drivers are a big subject, you should look into the WDF and probably get a book on it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/gg463268.aspx

Comment: Moreover, even for different versions of Windows the drivers may need to be changed/rewritten (or at least recompiled, depends on the situation).

Comment: A Windows UMDF driver doesn't need to be rewritten; it supports XP to 8 without recompilation. That's because it's user-mode, and doesn't depend on kernel changes.

Comment: @TonyTheLion How can I write a Bluetooth HID driver for windows? Is there any API's?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach should be to make your device appear as a [Bluetooth Human Interface Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Human_Interface_Device_Profile_.28HID.29): I believe that's how mainstream commercial devices do it.

Operating systems can provide generic driver support for HID-class devices, that's the point of pre-defining the device class.

Answer (score 0):

Like Unix originally suggested: if you keep your device compatible with block or character device driver code built-in to the OS, your device will be 'compatible'.